# Parsing an XML File - Losing My Mind

Tags: objective-c, ios, ios6, nsxmlparser

I've looked all over, including here and Google to find a simple way to parse an XML file for iOS6. Everything I've found is slightly different from the next causing extreme confusion on my part. So far this is what I have:

XMLParser.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@class Profile;

@interface XMLParser : NSObject <NSXMLParserDelegate>{
    NSData *profileData;

@private
    Profile *currentProfileObject;

    NSMutableArray *currentParsedBatch;
    NSMutableArray *currentParsedCharacterData;

    BOOL accumlatingParsedCharacterData;
    BOOL didAbortParsing;

    NSUInteger parsedProfilesCounters;
}

@property (copy, readonly) NSData *profileData;

-(id)initWithData:(NSData *)parseData;

@end
```

My XMLParser.m

```
#import "XMLParser.h"
#import "Profile.h"

//Create a delegate
@interface XMLParser () <NSXMLParserDelegate>
    @property (nonatomic, retain) Profile *currentProfileObject;
    @property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *currentParsedBatch;
    @property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *currentParsedCharacterData;
@end

@implementation XMLParser
@synthesize profileData, currentProfileObject, currentParsedBatch, currentParsedCharacterData;

-(id)initWithData:(NSData *)parseData{
    if(self = [super init]){
        profileData = [parseData copy];
    }
    return self;
}

-(void)addProfilesToList:(NSArray *)profiles{
    assert([NSThread isMainThread]);

}

-(void)main{
    self.currentParsedBatch = [NSMutableArray array];
    self.currentParsedCharacterData = [NSMutableString string];

    NSXMLParser *parser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithData:profileData];

    [parser setDelegate:self];
    [parser parse];

    if([self.currentParsedBatch count] > 0){
        [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(addProfilesToList:) withObject:self.currentParsedBatch waitUntilDone:NO];
    }

    self.currentParsedBatch = nil;
    self.currentProfileObject = nil;
    self.currentParsedCharacterData = nil;

    parser = nil;
}

/*
-(void)dealloc{
    [profileData release];
    [currentParsedCharacterData release];
    [currentParsedBatch release];

    [super dealloc];
}
*/

-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict{

    NSLog(@"Parsing...");

    if([elementName isEqualToString:@"profiles"]){
        Profile *profile = [[Profile alloc] init];
        self.currentProfileObject = profile;
        //[profile release];
        profile = nil;
    }
    else if([elementName isEqualToString:@"profile"]){
        NSLog(@"Parsing....");

        [self.currentProfileObject setLastName:[attributeDict valueForKey:@"lastName"]];
        [self.currentProfileObject setFirstName:[attributeDict valueForKey:@"firstName"]];
        [self.currentProfileObject setMobile:[attributeDict valueForKey:@"mobile"]];
        [self.currentProfileObject setPhone:[attributeDict valueForKey:@"phone"]];
        [self.currentProfileObject setEmail:[attributeDict valueForKey:@"email"]];
        [self.currentProfileObject setAltEmail:[attributeDict valueForKey:@"altEmail"]];
        [self.currentProfileObject setAddress:[attributeDict valueForKey:@"address"]];
        [self.currentProfileObject setCity:[attributeDict valueForKey:@"city"]];
        [self.currentProfileObject setState:[attributeDict valueForKey:@"state"]];
        [self.currentProfileObject setZipCode:[attributeDict valueForKey:@"zipCode"]];
        [self.currentProfileObject setProfilePicture:[attributeDict valueForKey:@"profilePicture"]];
    }
}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName
  namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI
 qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName{

    if([elementName isEqualToString:@"profile"]){
        [self.currentParsedBatch addObject:self.currentProfileObject];
        parsedProfilesCounters++;

    }
    else if([elementName isEqualToString:@"profiles"]){
        return;

    }
}

@end
```

Now in my appdelegate file I'm doing this:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    NSString *xmlFile = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"profileXML" ofType:@"xml"];
    NSData *xmlData = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:xmlFile];

    [[XMLParser alloc] init];


    MediDirectoryMasterViewController *masterViewController = [[MediDirectoryMasterViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MediDirectoryMasterViewController" bundle:nil];
    self.navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:masterViewController];
    self.window.rootViewController = self.navigationController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
```

None of this seems to work as I get no response from the log. If you couldn't tell, this is my first iOS app I've ever written so I'm not sure about how to go about all of this. Again, help is greatly appreciated as I'm starting to lose faith.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. If you think that calling `[[XMLParser alloc] init];` will cause to execute `XMLParser` `main` method then you are wrong. If you want to call any method of the class you should have reference to instance of that class and then call needed method. For example, in your case:

   ```
   XMLParser *parser = [[XMLParser alloc] initWithData:xmlData];
   [parser main];
   [parser release];
   ```
2. You have a lot of other bugs in your code that will take a lot of time to discuss. That is why I am suggesting you to read some simple examples from Apple Docs, i.e. [Your First iOS App](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphone101/Articles/00_Introduction.html). And if you are not familiar with classes and objects you should read about [object-oriented programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming) too.

Comment: I appreciate your help...and yes I have limited experience with OO programming. I finally had an epiphany last night and got the XML file parsed. This is being done in the XMLParser.m file - now I just need to figure out how to access the array in my MasterViewController.m file.

Comment: @EastCarolinaPirate you could create `@property (nonatomic, retain) NSArray *parsedObjects;` in `XMLParser` before `-(id)initWithData:(NSData *)parsedData;`. In `MasterViewController` save reference to `XMLParser` object. And the you could retrieve it by `parser.parsedData`;

Comment: Fantastic. Got it working! Thanks so much for your help. I have a formatting issue which I'll post another question. Thanks for your help again.